# Where is Ivan the Terrible's Library?

Tags: russia, byzantine-empire

During the confusion surrounding the capture of Constantinople by the Ottomans in 1453, the library of the Byzantine Paleologi Emperors was sent north to Moscow and installed by Ivan III under the Kremlin. The Kremlin was rebuilt in brick to protect this valuable new addition, which was nothing less than the library of the Roman Empire. Following the death of Ivan IV, the location of the library was lost.

Comment: Historians and archivists have been [searching for it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lost_Library_of_the_Moscow_Tsars) for a long while without success. The odds are slim that random people on the internet will know where it is or why they haven't found it. :-)

Comment: Perhaps the proper authorities in Moscow may be reading...? You found it after 9 minutes. What a prize for the glory of the third Rome, Moscow Russia!

Comment: This question would be improved if provided sources/citations.

Comment: All these stories about the library brought from Constantinople are speculations. There is no hard evidence of the existence of this library.

Comment: Those that would tell don't know. And if anyone does know, they're not likely to tell.

Answer (score 1):

As Denis observed right away, no such library is known to exist.